# React setState in a nested function

Tags: reactjs, jasmine

The "console.log(this.state.remaining)" in the startStop() shows the correct value. However the "setState()" in the nested function decrement() throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". What's wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    remaining: 0,
  }

startStop() {
    
console.log(this.state.remaining)

    function decrement() {
        this.setState({
          remaining: this.state.remaining + 1
        })
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
 const decrement = () => {
        this.setState({
          remaining: this.state.remaining + 1
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refer to methods inside the class, not in the self scope of a function.
Change to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    remaining: 0,
  }

startStop() {
    
console.log(this.state.remaining)

    decrement() {
        this.setState({
          remaining: this.state.remaining + 1
        })
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up declare that decrement using const and arrow function. So it works now. Is it possible because of the arrow function instead of declaring "function decrement()" ?